# Tukey's significance letters for each group

Tags: r, ggplot2, tukey

I'd like to add letters to show significant differences onto a ggplot.

This is my data frame, which has basal area (y-axis), treatment (x-axis), survey year (group) and L which are the letters derived from a Tukey's post hoc test from a glmer with an interaction between treatment and year.

```
hab <- structure(list(survey_year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2019", 
"2021"), class = "factor"), treatment = c("Clear Fell", "Clear Fell", 
"Clear Fell", "Clear Fell", "Clear Fell", "Clear Fell", "Clear Fell", 
"Clear Fell", "Clear Fell", "Clear Fell", "Early Transitioning Irregular", 
"Early Transitioning Irregular", "Early Transitioning Irregular", 
"Early Transitioning Irregular", "Early Transitioning Irregular", 
"Early Transitioning Irregular", "Early Transitioning Irregular", 
"Early Transitioning Irregular", "Early Transitioning Irregular", 
"Early Transitioning Irregular", "Early Transitioning Irregular", 
"Early Transitioning Irregular", "Early Transitioning Irregular", 
"Early Transitioning Irregular", "Early Transitioning Irregular", 
"Irregular", "Irregular", "Irregular", "Irregular", "Irregular", 
"Irregular", "Irregular", "Irregular", "Irregular", "Clear Fell", 
"Clear Fell", "Clear Fell", "Clear Fell", "Clear Fell", "Clear Fell", 
"Clear Fell", "Clear Fell", "Clear Fell", "Clear Fell", "Clear Fell", 
"Clear Fell", "Clear Fell", "Clear Fell", "Clear Fell", "Clear Fell", 
"Clear Fell", "Clear Fell", "Clear Fell", "Clear Fell", "Clear Fell", 
"Clear Fell", "Clear Fell", "Early Transitioning Irregular", 
"Early Transitioning Irregular", "Early Transitioning Irregular", 
"Early Transitioning Irregular", "Early Transitioning Irregular", 
"Early Transitioning Irregular", "Early Transitioning Irregular", 
"Early Transitioning Irregular", "Early Transitioning Irregular", 
"Early Transitioning Irregular", "Early Transitioning Irregular", 
"Early Transitioning Irregular", "Early Transitioning Irregular", 
"Early Transitioning Irregular", "Early Transitioning Irregular", 
"Early Transitioning Irregular", "Early Transitioning Irregular", 
"Early Transitioning Irregular", "Early Transitioning Irregular", 
"Early Transitioning Irregular", "Early Transitioning Irregular", 
"Early Transitioning Irregular", "Early Transitioning Irregular", 
"Early Transitioning Irregular", "Early Transitioning Irregular", 
"Early Transitioning Irregular", "Early Transitioning Irregular", 
"Early Transitioning Irregular", "Early Transitioning Irregular", 
"Early Transitioning Irregular", "Early Transitioning Irregular", 
"Early Transitioning Irregular", "Early Transitioning Irregular", 
"Early Transitioning Irregular", "Early Transitioning Irregular", 
"Early Transitioning Irregular", "Irregular", "Irregular", "Irregular", 
"Irregular", "Irregular", "Irregular", "Irregular", "Irregular", 
"Irregular", "Irregular", "Irregular", "Irregular", "Irregular", 
"Irregular", "Irregular", "Irregular", "Irregular", "Irregular", 
"Irregular", "Irregular", "Irregular", "Irregular", "Irregular", 
"Irregular", "Irregular", "Irregular", "Irregular", "Irregular", 
"Irregular", "Irregular", "Irregular", "Irregular", "Irregular", 
"Irregular", "Irregular"), basal_area = c(42, 42, 38, 36, 36, 
51, 28, 30, 58, 38, 24, 32, 30, 36, 28, 28, 30, 28, 30, 26, 28, 
28, 28, 36, 30, 22, 24, 22, 22, 20, 16, 18, 40, 18, 38, 38, 56, 
44, 44, 42, 38, 38, 42, 34, 42, 36, 38, 36, 28, 46, 34, 44, 36, 
60, 32, 52, 24, 34, 30, 32, 32, 30, 34, 34, 28, 30, 26, 28, 24, 
32, 26, 20, 36, 38, 48, 36, 28, 28, 38, 34, 38, 40, 38, 34, 28, 
40, 26, 32, 40, 36, 36, 36, 30, 26, 24, 16, 22, 24, 32, 22, 16, 
26, 26, 26, 18, 22, 16, 30, 32, 22, 26, 26, 18, 22, 18, 24, 44, 
24, 18, 18, 26, 36, 26, 14, 14, 20, 16, 16), L = c("c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "ac", "ac", "ac", "ac", 
"ac", "ac", "ac", "ac", "ac", "ac", "ac", "ac", "ac", "ac", "ac", 
"ab", "ab", "ab", "ab", "ab", "ab", "ab", "ab", "ab", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -128L))
```

This is the plot and associated code I have so far, which has basal area on the y-axis, treatment on the x-axis and the letters showing significance. But the letters are not grouped by survey year. Is there a way I can do this?

```
maxy <- 66 # set where I want the letters to be on the y-axis
ggplot(hab, aes(x=treatment, y = basal_area, colour=survey_year)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA, fill="white", outlier.colour=NA, position=position_dodge(width=0.9)) + 
  geom_point(position=position_jitterdodge()) +
  geom_text(aes(x=treatment, y = maxy, label = L, group=survey_year)) + 
  ylab("Basal area")+
  xlab("Treatment") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

As you can see the plot doesn't separate the letters by survey year, as Early Transitioning Irregular should have letters ac for 2019 and c for 2021, but right now they are overlapping.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: There are no mean values to show here as these are pairwise comparison results from a GLMM. And of course the results from this GLMM will be in the results section of the paper. I didn't provide this information as it was not relevant to the question I was asking.

Answer (score 2):

You need to also specify `position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)` to `geom_text()`.

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(hab, aes(treatment, 
                basal_area, 
                colour = survey_year, 
                label = L)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA,
               fill = "white", 
               outlier.colour = NA, 
               position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) + 
  geom_point(position = position_jitterdodge()) +
  geom_text(aes(y = maxy, 
                group = survey_year), 
            check_overlap = T, 
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), col = "black") + 
  ylab("Basal area") +
  xlab("Treatment") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]